# Exception while retrieving all available Site-Columns Sharepoint Client Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, site-column, exception-handling

I'm trying to retrieve all available site-columns from my sharepoint site. This is what I do:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
clientContext.Credentials = websService.Credentials;
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.AvailableFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
FieldCollection availableColFields = web.AvailableFields;
```

But I'm getting an exception here:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
>   Additional information: Requested value 'CheckBoxes' was not found.

It occurs at:

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

**NOTE:** This didn't happen earlier. I also created a new site-collection and there I got the same exception except this time the **Requested value '' was not found.** was not **Checkboxes.**

Can anyone please help me understand what causes this exception and what can be done to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

**Updated:**
I tried retrieving the columns using:

```
clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Fields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
FieldCollection availableColFields = web.Fields;
```

The issue is still there.

Comment: @pholpar, please check the update.

Comment: @pholpar, I'm trying to get the existing fields from Sharepoint Client Object Model.

Comment: could you please try out the suggestions (server side OM, REST) I wrote in the other, original thread, to be able to decide if it is a configuration problem or an issue with the client OM? Thanks!

Comment: Sure I'll do. Just wanted to inform that it was working before. Started facing this issue from few days back